# Flutter Routes within Bottom Navigation Bar

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to implement an outside Route file to keep all my routing information for my app within a single file.  I am now trying to using said route file within a BottomNavigationBar.

I have been watching countless videos and reading articles and have tried a number of different implementations

Routes.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:second_try/Screens/homeScreen.dart';
import 'package:second_try/Screens/agendaScreen.dart';

class RouteGenerator{
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings){
    final args = settings.arguments;

    switch (settings.name){
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=> homeScreen());
      case '/agenda':
        if (args is String) {
          return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=> agendaScreen());
        }
    }
  }}
```

---

bottomNavigation Widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:second_try/Screens/homeScreen.dart';
import 'package:second_try/Screens/agendaScreen.dart';
import 'package:second_try/routes.dart';

class bottomNavigation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _bottomNavigation createState() => _bottomNavigation();
}

class _bottomNavigation extends State<bottomNavigation> {
  int currentNavItem = 0;

  homeScreen home;
  agendaScreen agenda;
  List<Widget> pages;
  Widget currentPage;

  @override
  void initState(){
    home = homeScreen();
    agenda = agendaScreen();

    pages = [home, agenda];

    currentPage = home;
    super.initState();
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
      selectedFontSize: 16,
      currentIndex: currentNavItem,
      onTap: (int index) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/agenda');
        setState(() {
            currentNavItem = index;
            currentPage = pages[index];
          },
        );
      },
```

I am very new with flutter and getting a bit flustered being very lost with this implementation.  Thank you for the help and input in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/agenda');
```

Comment: didn't work.  I think that actually needs to be removed.  My intention with the Navigator.of was to be able to throw in parameters from above to be able to navigate to the different pages.

Comment: in that case you can use Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
          return AgendaScreen();
        }));

Comment: so that works, however I need to be able to implement the other screens as well.  I am trying to pass a number of different screens when their Item is pressed

Comment: you can do that by using function : for example ->  RaisedButton _buildRaisedButton(
      BuildContext context, String title, Color color, Widget page) {
    return RaisedButton(
      child: Text('$title'),
      color: color,
      colorBrightness: Brightness.dark,
      elevation: 11,
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
          return page;
        }));
      },
    );
  }

then you can use it by _buildRaisedButton(context, "Agenda", Colors.red, AgendaPage())